# Importing bootstrap js file

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I recently started using bootstrap installed from npm and i  have trouble importing the js file though

this is my main js file and  where i want to use all the tools

```
import * as bootstrap from '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

console.log(bootstrap);

my main .html file (where i put my js file)

```
<script src="Js/js_main.js" type="module"></script>
```

When i run my page the tools/plugins dosen't work so... Is there a way  to save this tools/plugins into your own js file like sass? or which is the best way to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Actually now in Bootstrap 5 is possible import the esm version of Bootstrap like that for example (code in the src/index.js file and node_modules folder on the same level of the js folder):

```
import * as bootstrap from '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js'

const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')

const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

In this way there is a problem with the path of Popper.js dependency.
You can open the bootstrap.esm.min.js and replace the import of Popper with:

```
import * as Popper from '../../../@popperjs/core/dist/esm/index.js'
```

The advantage in this way is that I can import only the component I want namely:

import {Popover} from '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js'

but remember that each import is an http request thereby you have to use webpack for example and in that case becomes more simple handle the project (in a different slightly different way from here).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood this, you are using bootstrap via npm to create html and js page. You are trying to get object of bootstrap js file but that is not the appropriate approach because it does not return anything.
You can use the absolute path of "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" in your html page so that bootstrap will be available in your html page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 5rem;
        }
        .starter-template {
            padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <!--MAIN HTML LAYOUT-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeey! Thanks! but is still a way to have them in a way that i can  upload to github or google drive, you know, instead of having to install all over again?

Comment: Thanks, if you like my answer you can mark up.
Instead of using npm you can create your own cdn path.